# Difference between #type and #theme in Render API

Tags: theming

I am reading this theming article http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/render/manipulate and I have a question.

This article has the following code:

```
$page['highlighted']['new_stuff'] = array(
'#type' => 'container',
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'my-container'),
);
$page['highlighted']['new_stuff']['heading'] = array(
'#type' => 'html_tag',
'#tag' => 'h2',
'#value' => t('Heading'),
'#attributes' => array('id' => 'my-heading'),
);
$page['highlighted']['new_stuff']['list'] = array(
'#theme' => 'item_list',
'#items' => array(
  'First item',
  'Second item',
  'Third item',
), 
);
```

I see that when you provide the #theme property you are telling the Render API to use the theme_item_list, and you pass it the #items variable. But isn't that exactly what you are doing when you set type to #html_tag, you're using the theme_html_tag and passing it variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose is a little different:

- `'#type'` is telling to the render API to merge what returned from [`hook_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7)
- `'#theme'` is saying to the render API which theme function to use

In the example you are making, the theme function used is [`theme_html_tag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_html_tag/7) because [`system_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7) returns the following data.

```
  $types['html_tag'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'html_tag',
    '#pre_render' => array('drupal_pre_render_conditional_comments'),
    '#attributes' => array(),
    '#value' => NULL,
  );
```

If `'#theme'` were set to `'tag_html'`, `theme_tag_html()` would be the theme used by the render API.

Comment: Thats very interesting. Is there a reason we'd use #type if we could just directly use the #theme?

Comment: with `'#type'`, you can set more than just `'#theme'`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I see that both are setting properties which are really fields being passed to the template. Isn't this how it works? What can #type do more?

Comment: The properties returned by `hook_element_info()` includes `#pre_render`, `#process`, `#theme_wrappers`; setting `#type` you can potentially set all those, not just `#theme`.

Comment: I asked their if really #type is necessary https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3309942